# web service (asmx) port number added atomically in the invoke button

Tags: web-services, iis

I have an web service (.asmx) in in IIS. If click invoke button for the web service via machine name and port it is fine.

```
http:// example:1111/mymethod
```

However, if I access it via url http:// example.com/mymethod and click invoke button again,
I see the URL changes to `http:// example.com:1111/mymethod`. So port number is added in automatically.

It is on iis 7, can anyone help?

Comment: Realized that it is because the wsdl file created by microsoft contains port number in url. Any idea why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

worked out this now.

IT setup the site on our load balancer, which redirects to the server on port 1111. As a result, IIS will receive a request to my url on port 1111 and Microsoft code will add port number in the wsdl file.

So I asked IT to redirect to the server on port 80, and on IIS I setup the host header to be my url and port 80. This solves the issue.